# ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set properly and it is valid, I am able to build android project locally from terminal using "ionic build android" but when I start build from Jenkins, I am getting below error(this is the log from jenkins console). I have also set the environment variable from manage jenkins -> Configure systems -> environment variable.

```
+ ionic build android
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

 Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-android@5.0.0 or newer.


Running command: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/csgtools/workspace/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/csgtools/workspace


add to body class: platform-android

will push strings array {"name":"lang","titles":["English (US)","English (UK)"],"values":["en-us","en-gb"]}

android preferences file was successfully generated
Running command: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/csgtools/workspace/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[1m[Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path: /Users/prakash/Library/Android/sdk
Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.]
[22m    [1mError:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/csgtools/workspace/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2[22m
[1m
[22m
Finished: SUCCESS
```

This is my shell build script in jenkins:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
cd $WORKSPACE
echo $PATH
chmod -R 777 *

ionic build android
```

Comment: And `/Users/prakash/Library/Android/sdk` really exists?

Comment: @ Boris Shchegolev, yes it is there.. Also it is proper android sdk path.. It is taking when we build from terminal. But not from the Jenkins shell build scripts

Comment: Did you solve this? I have exactly the same problem.